# error Call to undefined function get_header() in

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I just downloaded a new template, when I wanted to try it, I got a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header()
```

here is my index.php

```
<?php 
global $SMTheme;

get_header(); 

get_template_part('theloop');

get_template_part('navigation');

get_footer();

?>
```

Comment: Tried adding the variable to the functions? IE `$SMTheme->get_header();`

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in comments, I'm going to assume the functions of `get_header()` etc are somewhere in the class that $SMTheme is defined as.

So, given that, you should call the functions like this:

```
$SMTheme->get_header(); 

$SMTheme->get_template_part('theloop');

$SMTheme->get_template_part('navigation');

$SMTheme->get_footer();
```